# How to find frequencies of a days of a certain year using mapreduce and pyspark

Tags: datetime, hadoop, mapreduce, pyspark

I have a text file (61Gb) containing on each line, a string representing a date, e.g. Thu Dec 16 18:53:32 +0000 2010

Iterating the file on a single core would take too long, therefore I would like to use Pyspark and the Mapreduce technology to quickly find frequencies of lines for a day in a certain year.

What I think is a good start:

```
import dateutil.parser
text_file = sc.textFile('dates.txt')
date_freqs = text_file.map(lambda line: dateutil.parser.parse(line)) \
        .map(lambda date: date + 1) \
        .reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a + b)
```

Unfortunately I can't understand how to filter on a certain year and reduce by key. The key is the day.

Example output:

Thu Dec 16 26543

Thu Dec 17 345
etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As alluded to in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37214039/1314654), `dateutil.parser.parse` returns a [datetime object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) which has `year`, `month`, and `day` attributes:

```
>>> dt = dateutil.parser.parse('Thu Dec 16 18:53:32 +0000 2010')
>>> dt.year
2010
>>> dt.month
12
>>> dt.day
16
```

Starting with this RDD:

```
>>> rdd = sc.parallelize([
...     'Thu Oct 21 5:12:38 +0000 2010',
...     'Thu Oct 21 4:12:38 +0000 2010',
...     'Wed Sep 22 15:46:40 +0000 2010',
...     'Sun Sep 4 22:28:48 +0000 2011',
...     'Sun Sep 4 21:28:48 +0000 2011'])
```

Here's how you can get the counts for all year-month-day combinations:

```
>>> from operator import attrgetter
>>> counts = rdd.map(dateutil.parser.parse).map(
...     attrgetter('year', 'month', 'day')).countByValue()
>>> counts
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {(2010, 9, 22): 1, (2010, 10, 21): 2, (2011, 9, 4): 2})
```

To get the output you want:

```
>>> for k, v in counts.iteritems():
...     print datetime.datetime(*k).strftime('%a %b %y'), v
...
Wed Sep 10 1
Thu Oct 10 2
Sun Sep 11 2
```

If you want counts for only a certain year, you can filter the RDD before doing the count:

```
>>> counts = rdd.map(dateutil.parser.parse).map(
...    attrgetter('year', 'month', 'day')).filter(
...    lambda (y, m, d): y == 2010).countByValue()
>>> counts
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {(2010, 9, 22): 1, (2010, 10, 21): 2})
```

Answer (score 1):

Something along the lines of this might be a good start:

```
import dateutil.parser
text_file = sc.textFile('dates.txt')
date_freqs = text_file.map(lambda line: dateutil.parser.parse(line))
    .keyBy((_.year, _.month, _.day)) // somehow get the year, month, day to key by
    .countByKey()
```

Answer (score 0):

I should add that dateutil is not standard in Python. If you do not have sudo right on your cluster, this could pose a problem. As a solution I would like to propose using datetime:

```
import datetime
def parse_line(d):
    f = "%a %b %d %X %Y"
    date_list = d.split()
    date = date_list[:4]
    date.append(date_list[5])
    date = ' '.join(date)
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(date, f)

counts = rdd.map(parse_line)\
    .map(attrgetter('year', 'month', 'day'))\
    .filter(lambda (y, m, d): y == 2015)\
    .countByValue()
```

I am interested in better solutions using: Parquet, Row/Columns etc.